# Routing to root (Beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

this is my first time posting to stackoverflow. I am learning Ruby on Rails and i want to ask the reason why my app doesn't redirect to the root i specified in my routes.rb.
I already deleted the public/index.html and also removed it from git.

```
Jba::Application.routes.draw do
    get "home/index"
    root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What do you see in the browser?

Comment: I dont see any error. I still see the welcome aboard rails page.

Comment: Browser cache I guess since you're viewing content that doesn't exist anymore? Try another one or empty the cache, force reload ...

Comment: I just cleared my cached and it now works as i wanted. I didn't know its that simple. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you clear the cache on your local browser in order to view the changes you've made to your code.